# SAP crystal server Error CRR 00143 API /rpt/export?mime_type=

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm having trouble calling the API
localhost:8080/biprws/infostore/{reportId}/rpt/export?mime_type=application/pdf&startPageNumber=1

This request requires that the report be refreshed (by getting a new instance). (CRR 00143)

[image]

What problem should I solve to export PDF files?